# Operating on each generated entity of a list comprehension

Tags: python, string, split, list-comprehension

I am trying to generate a list using list comprehension and I want to do an operation on each generated entity. Something like:

```
a=['1','2','3']
b=['a','b','c']
temp = [[x,y] for x in a for y in b]
c=[]
for t in temp:
    c.append("".join(t))
```

I tried something like:

```
a=['1','2','3']
b=['a','b','c']
c = ",".join([x,y] for x in a for y in b)
```

I know this won't work because the `split` function has been given a list of lists instead of list of strings. Is there any better way to do this in one go?

The output I am trying to get is `['1a','1b','1c','2a','2b','2c','3a','3b','3c']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> [x + y for x in a for y in b]
['1a', '1b', '1c', '2a', '2b', '2c', '3a', '3b', '3c']
```

Comment: Ah! I missed a pretty obvious solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The same using itertools:

```
from itertools import product

print map(''.join, product(['1','2','3'],['a','b','c']))
```

OR without:

```
print map(lambda y: map(lambda x: x+y, a), b)
```

OR if you have a list of integers:

```
print map(''.join, product(map(str, xrange(1,4)), ['a','b','c']))
```

Comment: Why do you use list in there? Defeats the purpose of using a generator

Comment: @Artsiom How will this work if one of the lists is a list of integer and each element needs to be converted to a string?

Comment: You can use it the following way: map(''.join, product(map(str, xrange(1,4)),['a','b','c']))

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used map() a lot hence my questions :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product
[x+y for x,y in product(a,b)]
```

or

```
from itertools import product, starmap
starmap(str.__add__, product(a,b))
```

Comment: How will these work if a and b are homogenous lists of different datatypes, say int and string?

Comment: @Guruprasad, product will work with any iterables, you will have trouble joining an int to a string though. You could convert them to str before joining like `["%s%s"%i for i in product(a,b)]` i suppose